# What did Loki mean when he called Natasha (Black Widow) "Dreykov's daughter"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012

> Natalia "Natasha" Alianovna Romanova born circa 1928 and was raised from her youth by a Russian soldier Ivan Petrovich Bezukhov after she was orphaned when enemy soldiers attacked Stalingrad.
>
> It is rumored that Black Widow is somehow related to the last ruling czars of Russia, but this has yet to be proven. Not much is known about Black Widow's history prior to World War II other than she was born as Natalia Romanova in Stalingrad, Russia to unknown parents. Nazis set fire to the building that Natasha and her parents were living in and her mother threw Natasha out of the window into the arms of a Russian soldier named Ivan Petrovitch, who was serving in the army at the time.
> <sub>[Comic Vine](http://www.comicvine.com/black-widow/4005-3200/)</sub>

In the movie 'Thor', Thor refers to Agent Coulson as "Son of Coul". So using that same speech pattern, does it mean that when Loki asked her "Can you wipe out that much red, Dreykov's Daughter?" was he was actually giving her a hint that he knew her true origins and who her real parents were? She did seem to register a brief shock at his statement.

Comment: Coulson = Coul's Son = Son Of Coul. I always understood it as Thor interpreting the pronunciation of the name literally. I don't see how that figures into Loki's line to Natasha.

Comment: @phantom42, I could be mistaken but I interpreted Loki's comment, as well as his and Thor's speech patterns in general to be a light attempt at mixing aspects of Forsooth speech with common English. Stark even mocks Thor's speech patterns and appearance during their woods battle at their first meeting.
http://www.scatoday.net/node/4794

Comment: Pretty sure you're misunderstanding what Loki's saying: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16608/what-are-these-events-from-widows-past

Comment: @Morgan - It's just Thor mistaking Coulson's name for a Scandanavian one, names like Anderson (son of Ander), Erickson (son of Erick), and of course Odinson (son of Odin).

Comment: I seriously doubt that movieverse Black Widow was born in 1928...

Comment: @evilsoup, She does seem pretty spry for an older lady.

Comment: @evilsoup If the Infinity Formula exists in the Movie Universe it's very possible she is much older than she looks.

Comment: @SystemDown - It also follows with Dottir (daughter). As an example, a man named Aelf Wargunsson would have a daughter named Brighid Aelfsdottir and a son named Erick Aelfsson.

Comment: In "Captain America: The Winter Soldier", the android/doctor/creepy-thing-on-the-computer-screen said that she was born in 1984. So, I think they changed it around in the Marvel Cinematic Universe so she could be younger...

Comment: @evilsoup Black Widow super-power, as listed in Top Trumps: ‘Keeping It Tight — 10/10’

Comment: If her parents are unknown, how does she have a patronym?

Comment: @phantom42 hes not just interpreting the pronunciation literally, the origin last names ending in -son are generally from people who were sons of the person with that name, like Thor ODINson :)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

He's not calling her "Dreykov's Daughter". What he's doing is listing out her "crimes".

> Loki: Can you? Can you wipe out that much red? Dreykov's daughter, Sao Paulo, the hospital fire. Barton told me everything. Your ledger is dripping. It's gushing red, and you think saving a man no more virtuous than yourself will change anything?

These are all incidents in which she is trying to redeem herself for.  Dreykov's daughter is someone else, probably someone she harmed in some way.

Comment: CL4PTR4P, using your answer as a springboard for further research, it appears that you were most likely correct. Even using the pauses in Loki's speech patterns, it does appear that "Drakov's Daughter" is in fact a part of a list. I guess I was reading more into the comment than was necessary.

Comment: For the record, there's no DRAKOV anywhere in the Marvel canon. It seems to have been invented for the movie...

Comment: @Richard- Thanks, sometimes it's hard to know what they're fabricating out of whole-cloth.

Comment: Interesting answer, but the inflection in the movie always had me thinking Loki was calling her "Drakov's daughter." It is definitely open to interpretation, so I admit you're answer is possible and makes sense, but Tom Hiddleston's delivery sure seems like he's calling her that.

Comment: He's definitely referring to something she did rather than calling her that. I assume it was someone she assassinated.

Comment: If Drakov's Daughter is a person she killed (or did something else nasty to), the natural way to address her would be by her own name. I see three possibilities; either she really is Drakov's daughter (perhaps in a figurative sense), Drakov's Daughter is not a person but some well known event or location or Drakov's daughter hadn't been given a name before she died. Without any canon on Drakov, it's just guessing.

Comment: @Clearer: Or Loki didn't know her name. If I'm going to refer to your daughter, without knowing their name, I'm going to say "Clearer's daughter".

Comment: @MyCodeSucks That's a possibility. I want to believe that Loki would be able to figure out her name (he seems to have a knack for guessing the names of everybody else). If the event was important, my guess is anyone would be able to find her name too. You don't have to refer to my daughter as "Clearer's daughter" -- her name is Sigrid.

Comment: @Clearer - also, keep in mind that Loki only knows this stuff because Clint (Hawkeye) told him. It's entirely possible that when Clint was telling the story, he never referred to the daughter by name. He could have told Loki something like "We couldn't get to Drakov himself, so Natalie decided to kill his daughter and then get Drakov at the funeral."

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, Drakov is slovakian for Dragons. I can't find a reference for a Slovakian character referred to as a dragon, but it is only a few hours from Budapest

Comment: Consider Loki got his information on BW from Barton, if either he or Nat ever knew the girls name it's plausible Barton didn't give the name to Loki, e.g. Loki: "Barton, quick, give me a run down on 'Black Widow' ". Barton: "Well boss she did x, y, z and put pressure on this guy Drakov to sign a deal by killing his daughter and told him the rest of his family was next". Yes Loki and Barton hung out for a couple of days, but they were _extremely_ busy days. Also consider the fact that women in our culture are often defined by their male relatives https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corey_Cogdell

Answer (score 13):

We learn in *Black Widow* (2021) that [General *Dreykov*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Dreykov) was the man behind the 'Red Room', a clandestine super-soldier project focusing on brainwashing young girls, including the titular Black Widow.

Prior to her defection to the US (but after she'd been compromised and turned against her handlers), she worked with Clint Barton to kill Dreykov by demolishing the building that was his base of operations. His daughter was seen, by her, entering the building. She could have delayed the explosion, but only at the risk that Dreykov might leave.

[image: Dreykov's daughter Antonia, as spotted in "Black Widow" (2021)]

It may interest you to know that daughter actually

> survived as [The Taskmaster](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Taskmaster).

Comment: Either you think the question is a duplicate, or you think the two questions are different enough to answer both. Don't have your cake and eat it by copy-pasting the same answer to earn double rep *and* using your dupehammer to close one of the questions. That smells really iffy.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I don't see any problem with answering it, then dupehammering *after* realising that it's a dupe.

Comment: That all being said, I did raise precisely this issue several years ago when I pointed out that an answer to one would be an answer to the other.

Comment: I’ve reopened the question, the question here is a slight misunderstanding that has been answered above. This doesn’t really answer that question but what Loki was actually referring to. This is a good answer to this question though you may want to edit it slightly to address the misunderstanding.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - For me the test is whether you can entirely duplicate an answer, which you can. I shall defer to our modly masters though.

Comment: @Valorum my point above is though that you can’t really, a good answer here would address the misheard line which you’ve ignored so far. Like I said though with the updated canon this is a good answer but a slight edit would make it fit this question better.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I've addressed it by putting the word Dreykov into italics. And the other answer includes the actual quote from the movie, so what would be the point of repeating it?

Answer (score -2):

Dreykovs douchter he meens with that is that dreykov raised natasha in the redroom its not bc there connected genetically i know this movie did not exist yet but maby in the marvel comics the name dreykov oready popped up ones ore twice anyways natasha i think is not genetically related to dreykov loki prob just meens he knows natashas background storys and were she was raised bc when he sed this the rest of the advengers did not know ab natashas history yet. I think he just ment that she was raised in the redroom ( the creator is dreykov ) this gets out when the movie the black widow was released. I think loki ment that dreykov was kind of a adoptive parent of natasha and hundreds of other girls to.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence that this is correct?  The script quoted in the first answer seems to contradict this reading, since that makes it obvious that Loki is not _addressing_ Black Widow as "Drakov's daughter," he is referring to someone else.

Comment: Hi id like to change my answer i just did some recearch loki didnt call natasha dreykovs doughter he talked to natasha telling her he knows natasha killed dreykovs doughter if you lisnen clearly and you saw the black widow movie were natasha fired up the hospital as atempt to koll dreykov his doughter was there aswel loki sed to natasha these words: can you wipe out that mutch red, dreykovs doughter the hospital fire. Witch he means is that he is calling out what she did in the pass: fire up the hospital as edempt to kill dreykov while natasha knew his doughter was there.

Comment: You can just [edit] your post and rewrite it as much as you like.