# What is Black Widow's history?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification

Black Widow is a very confusing character to me.

- Where does she come from?
- Was she just an average soldier taken for science experiments? I have heard about this Russian serum tested on her and ever since she had been mentally and physically enhanced but apart from that do we have any sort of proof to her current character?
- Does her mother have to do anything with these abilities?

Answer (score 5):

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, Natasha Romanov (AKA Natalia Romanov, AKA "*[Black Widow](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Widow)*") is not the product of the [enhanced serum](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Soldier_Serum) but rather a Soviet programme designed to take promising young girls and train them to become anti-Western assassins.

We see the Soviet spy training programme (confirmed in [an interview](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2015/01/28/marvels-agent-carter-dottie-black-widow) to be the precursor to the Black Widow programme) in Agent Carter. This regime includes brainwashing, physical and mental abuse, fight training, marksmanship and the killing of live targets (and each other) in order to demonstrate worthiness to 'graduate'.

Under the cover of a ballet school, Natalia was trained as an assassin, then sent on a series of missions culminating in her defection to the west, whereupon she became a member of S.H.I.E.L.D.

Her talents and abilities can be best described as [peak human](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Peak_Human_Condition) rather than actually superhuman.

Comment: Okay but why was she called as Drakov's daughter by Loki in Avenger movie. And also Loki asks whether she can wipe out that much of red from her history? What are we missing there? 

Comment: @user11713 - See ["What did Loki mean when he called Natasha (Black Widow) “Drakov's daughter”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33546/what-did-loki-mean-when-he-called-natasha-black-widow-drakovs-daughter) for more info. The short answer is that we don't know who Drakov was or what Natasha did to his daughter (killed her, presumably, or tortured her to punish/blackmail Drakov).

Comment: Did the OP say they were talking about the MCU? Or did you just *decide* they meant in the MCU?

Comment: @RedCaio - The only reference to Drakov's daughter is in the MCU, not the comics.

Comment: But the question didn't mention that. Just the comment.

Comment: @redcaio - I've always been a lucky guesser :-)